# Fixed position until scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was hoping someone could help me here.

Im trying to fix a div at the bottom of the page until the user scrolls it will then scroll up too.

Comment: What have you tried? How about some code? This will really help your question.

Answer (score 3):

There is some ambiguity in your question for whether you want the div to position at the bottom of the whole document or initially position at the bottom of the window and then scroll.

### At Bottom of Document

Positioning at the bottom of the document (no matter how long the document is) is easy.  Just set this CSS on the div:

```
#yourDiv {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This will position it at the end of the document.  If the document is shorter than the window height, it will not be at the bottom of the window, but at the end of the document.  If the document is taller than the window height, then it's location at the bottom of the document will initially be below the bottom of the window and will only be visible when the document is scrolled upwards.

### At Bottom of Window, then Scroll in that Position

If you want it to initially appear at the bottom of the window, but then scroll in that position on the page as the page is scrolled, you can't do it with pure CSS, but will need javascript to position it.

In pseudo code:

```
wHeight = get height of window
oHeight = get height of your object that you want to place at the bottom
Then, set the position on your object using absolute position:
    o.style.position = "absolute";
    o.style.top = (wHeight - oHeight) + "px";
```

This will maintain that object at a fixed number of pixels from the top of the document even as you scroll.

Here's a working example using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ZV2bM/

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">This is my footer</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #777; 
    height: 4000px;
    padding: 0;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute; 
    text-align: center; 
    background-color: #444;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

JS:

```
var pos = $(window).height() - $("#footer").height();
$("#footer").css({top: pos});
```

Comment: wow thanks, However this is where i got to with my version... http://jsfiddle.net/PnUmM/121/\

Comment: @jimmy - Is that jsfiddle doing exactly what you want?  Or do you want to fix that?  And, what is the exact behavior you want?  Your question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: In this example... http://jsfiddle.net/PnUmM/121/ Its nearly working however. When the user scrolls i would like the little sticky black bar to snap to the bottom of the blue div (not the top, which it currently does). Im not sure nesting the black sticky div inside the top wrap div is the way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position:fixed; bottom:0px; right:10px;">
```

or whatever for the right attribute.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I have already fixed the div to the bottom. However i want it to scroll normally once the user starts to scroll. see this. http://www.nikeskateboarding.com/

Comment: ok. I think I may see... it would help to have a little code with the question, but based on what I understand, you could set the window.onscroll event to a function that changes the divs style attribute of position fixed to whatever is needed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PnUmM/121/ <--- basically this is where i have got to however when i scroll i would like the little black bar to go to the bottom of the 'blue' div.

Answer (score 0):

That site just positions the div at the bottom and makes it scroll normally. If you want that, you can just use:

```
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;"></div>
```

Another advantage of this is that it works in all browsers, while `position: fixed` doesn't work in some older browsers like Internet Explorer 6.